# UITableViewCells created using UIViews not responding to gesture recognisers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm putting this up as a questions even though I have a solution because I'm curious if anyone knowns more about the internals of what is going on.

The scenario is a client project I've just started on which has a really old codebase. When running on iOS7, gesture recognisers that had been added to table view cells (to pick up taps), where no firing. iOS5&6 no problem. Just iOS7.

After a lot of digging around in the code and experimenting I noticed that the root control in the xibs containing the cells where UIView's rather than UITableViewCells. The classes assigned to the root view were extensions of UITableViewCells so when the xib was inflated into objects the correct class was created.

But when running on iOS7, something about this didn't want to fire the recognisers. In my experiments I converted one of these xibs to have a UITableViewCell as the root control instead of a UIView and everything started working.

My assumption is that when compiling the xibs, XCode is doing something different depending on the root control in the xib, even though it has a custom UITableViewCell class assigned.

So I have a solution to fix my problem (great), but I'd be interested to know if anyone has a more detailed explanation of why using a UIView as a root control in a xib, even though it compiles and (mostly) works, is not kosher.

Oh and YES I am going to fix the xibs to have the correct root control. :)